# What is the regex for Hindi numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write regex to check validation for Hindi natural numbers.

Regex for natural numbers in English language is : `/^[1-9][0-9]*$/`

Already Googled it but was not able to find any solution.  Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Simple as this:

```
/^[१-९][०-९]*$/
```

Check the working here:https://regex101.com/r/lA6rS5/2

Comment: Hey thanks, but it is not working. I am working on java-script.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match Hindi numbers using unicode then use this regex:

```
/^[\u0967-\u096F][\u0966-\u096F]*$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vG6hQ2/4)

#### [Check all Hindi unicode points here](http://decodeunicode.org/de/devanagari)

Comment: I am using Java Script over here and there is no u modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex as char in Hindi should start with Hindi char and you can add special char(as optional).

```js
/^[\u0900-\u097F]*[\s]?([\u0900-\u097F]*[\s]?)*?$/
```